# Does undefined behavior affect static_assert?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, static-assert

Consider the following code:

```
SomeType x=getX();
for(auto mask = 1u<<(CHAR_BIT*sizeof x - 1);/*...*/;/*...*/)
{
    static_assert(sizeof mask>=sizeof x, "Type of numeric parameter is too long");
    /*...*/
}
```

Here, `mask` will have type `unsigned`. Suppose `SomeType` is `long long`. Then the initialization of `mask` will have undefined behavior due to shifting by too much. But OTOH, there's a `static_assert`, which checks that undefined behavior can't happen at runtime (because the code would fail to compile).

But since UB can lead to time paradoxes and other surprises, I'm not so sure that `static_assert` is guaranteed to actually work in this case. Is there any reason to be sure of this? Or should this code be redone to make `static_assert` appear before initialization of `mask`?

Comment: You can use `auto mask = 1u; static_assert(...); mask <<= HAR_BIT*sizeof x-1;` to avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: UB is tricky.  Just move the assert above the calculation to make sure it has correct values like `SomeType x=getX(); static_assert(sizeof(x) < whatever_value_you_need, "Type of numeric parameter is too long"); ...`

Comment: @RSahu I've edited the example code to be less simplified and closer to my actual use case.

Comment: @Ruslan, the updated code makes a stronger case for moving the `static_assert` right after `SomeType x = ...;`. What's the point of doing that in a loop?

Comment: @RSahu to avoid repeating the type of mask. I.e. if I need to e.g. extend the mask type, I'd just replace `1u` with `1ull` in one place. But if I explicitly declare `unsigned mask` beforehand to do the `static_assert` before, I get two issues: 1) mask survives after the loop (needs additional scope to avoid this), 2) changing type in the expression also needs an additional change of type of `mask`.

Comment: Could we see this with more parentheses? I'm a little unhappy seeing the left shift and multiply and sizeof and subtraction without any of them.

Comment: @Tim: I think it's `(1u << (CHAR_BIT*(sizeof x))) - 1`

Comment: @BenVoigt you've mistaken: addition/subtraction has higher precedence than shifts. But OK, this simply proves Tim's point. I'll add some parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing here actually answers the question

Answer (score 2):

Since you know you are going to use `unsigned` as the type for `mask`, there is no need to rely on `mask` to do the `static_assert`. Do it right after before the loop begins.

```
SomeType x = getX();
static_assert(sizeof 1u >= sizeof x, "Type of numeric parameter is too long");

for(auto mask = 1u << CHAR_BIT*sizeof x-1; /*...*/; /*...*/)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

A cleaner option would be to use a helper function.

```
template <typename RetType, typename SomeType>
RetType make_mask(RetType in, SomeType const& x)
{
   static_assert(sizeof in >= sizeof SomeType, "Type of numeric parameter is too long");
   return (in << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof SomeType)-1);
}
```

and use

```
for(auto mask = make_mask(1u, x); /*...*/; /*...*/)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you've repeated `1u` and added to the maintenance cost (alluded to by Ruslan in comments, but not in the question)

Comment: @TimRandall, fair point. I updated the answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

If `SomeType` is an integral type and you are using C++11 or newer, you might be able to eliminate the assert altogether by using:

```
auto one = std::make_unsigned<SomeType>::type(1);
for(auto mask = one << CHAR_BIT*sizeof x-1; /*...*/; /*...*/)
{
    /*...*/
}
```